Validation no input com mensagem de erro para quando não exista o item no banco de dados
Tenho um form que da submit para modificar uma peça cadastrada no banco, mas gostaria que aparecesse uma mensagem de erro e impedisse o submit quando essa peça não exista. O atributo utilizado para identificar é "CodigoSistema" (vem de outras referencias de outro sistema). A principio está funcionando, pois quando digito um codigo que não existe, o modal não da submit e fica na mesma tela, porém não apresenta nenhuma mensagem de erro que é o que preciso. Estou usando C# com HTML AspNetCore
Form:
<label asp-for="CodigoSistema"></label>
 <input required asp-for="CodigoSistema" type="text" class="form-control mb-2" id="CodigoSistema" placeholder="Código">
<span asp-validation-for="CodigoSistema" class="text-danger"></span>
                    <div class="text-danger">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
                    </div>
                
Script:

```lang-js 
$('#formSaidaEstoque').on(function (event) {

     var form = $(this);
     var url = form.attr('action');

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/Estoque/SaidaEstoque",
         data: form.serialize(), 
         success: function (response) {
             if (response.success) {
                 
                 $('#modalSaidaEstoque').modal('hide');
                 location.reload(); 
             } else {
                 
                 $('#modalSaidaEstoque .modal-header').html(response);
             }
         }
     });
 });


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
